# T-SQL Max Weight Query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a table with these columns:

```
BatchNumber, BagNumber, BagWeight, CumulativeWeight
```

Each batch can have up to 30 bags and the other columns are self-explanatory.

What I need is a query which finds the maximum cumulative weight for each batch, here is what I have so far.

```
DECLARE @HighestBagNumber INT;
DECLARE @BatchNumber CHAR(8);

SET @BatchNumber = 37708;

SELECT @HighestBagNumber = MAX(BagNumber) 
FROM FSD3BagLog 
WHERE BatchNumber = @BatchNumber

SELECT BatchNumber, BagNumber, CumulativeWeight 
FROM FSD3BagLog 
WHERE BagNumber = @HighestBagNumber 
  AND BatchNumber = @BatchNumber
```

This works for one batch at a time but I need it to look at all batches in the table. As you might be able to tell, I am a total beginner so please be as critical as you want, its all good.

Comment: It's not usually a good idea to *store* derived data. `CumulativeWeight` looks like it could easily be *calculated*. All you do by storing it is introduce the possibility for it to be wrong/inconsistent.

Comment: Damien, Thanks for the advice, the table is actually 2 data columns and 4 derived columns using SUBSTRING to disect a long string in the second column. Perhaps I should have included this in my initial question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes `GROUP BY` seems right, with the proper storage model it should be:

```
SELECT BatchNumber, COUNT(BagNumber), SUM(BagWeight)
FROM FSD3BagLog
GROUP BY BatchNumber
```

Result: `100, 30, 600`
*(Where batch number = 100, there are 30 per batch, and weight of each bag = 20)*

But based on you current working query it looks like you are storing denomalizing the data and storing cumulative weight as you go, probably using triggers or some other code that fires when the table is updated.

So if cumulative weight represents the total weight of a given batch, you can get rid of it and use the query above.

If cumulative weight is something else, such as total of all bags up to a certain point in time, you can still get rid of it.  In that case you would simple do something like:

```
SELECT BatchNumber, SUM(BagWeight) AS CumulativeWeight
FROM FSD3BagLog
WHERE ModifiedDate <= '2018-08-11 06:18:00'
```

Given you are storing `ModifiedDate` as a column on your table, this will give you the cumulative weight of all bags up to today at 6:18 AM.

Comment: Shane, I have marked this post as the answer because of your explanation you included. As I said, you can tell I am a total beginner and this becomes blatant when you consider I never thought to use GROUP BY!! Thanks for the answer, you have just saved an engineer many hours of trawling!

Comment: Great!  Please remember with database technology, it is all based on set theory.  If you find yourself trying to do stuff with procedural logic in stored procedures or with triggers, you are short circuiting the database and fighting against it.  This article has some good stuff about the tension between Agile development and good db design: https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/agile-database-development/

Answer (score 0):

Simple `GROUP BY` should do the job:

```
SELECT BatchNumber, MAX(CumulativeWeight)
FROM my_table
GROUP BY BatchNumber
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with batches_ranked as
(
    select BatchNumber, BagNumber,
        CumulativeWeight = sum(Weight) over (partition by BatchNumber order by BagNumber),
        [Rank] = row_number() over (partition by BatchNumber order by BagNumber desc)
    from FSD3BagLog
)
select * from batches_ranked where [Rank] = 1
```

sounds like you have CumulativeWeight stored in the table, if that is always increasing with BagNumber then you can simplify the query to just:

```
select BatchNumber, max(BagNumber), max(CumulativeWeight)
from FSD3BagLog group by BatchNumber
```